# How do I handle output in a shell script from a PHP script that has output to either STDOUT or STDERR?

Tags: php, bash, shell, sh, zsh

Suppose I have the following PHP script being run on the PHP CLI in a shell script:

```
<?php
# foo.php

$a = rand(1,5);

if ($a == 1) {
    fwrite(STDOUT, 'normal condition');
} else {
    fwrite(STDERR, 'error condition');
}
```

The script is run in the shell like so:

```
php foo.php
```

How do I handle the output from the PHP script in the shell based on whether the output is to STDERR or STDOUT? For instance, if the output from the PHP script is STDOUT, write it to a CSV file, but if the output is to STDERR, write the output to an error log file.

Comment: You may need to clarify 'handle'. Is it ok to create both files each time? I so, the answer below should work.  Can you add post-processing to remove an empty file? Also, how large is the expected output? If it's relatively small, in could be captured in a variable, and then written to a file.

Comment: Your question is tagged _bash_, _zsh_  and _sh_. We don't know which shell you are going to use.

Comment: @Gairfowl Ideally only one file would be created/updated depending on the source of the output. If post-processing can remove the empty file as part of handling either outcome, I'd like to know that. Output would be relatively small, about a kilobyte.

Comment: @user1934428 I am using zsh, though I can also use bash. Ideally this would work in either shell, but I'd also like to know shell-specific differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possibilities that produce a single output file.

---

Option 1 - redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to separate files, then remove empty files:

```bash
php file.php > ./data.csv 2> ./error.txt
[[ ! -s ./data.csv ]] && rm ./data.csv
[[ ! -s ./error.txt ]] && rm ./error.txt
```

The `! -s` test will be true if a file is zero-length. This version uses some fairly common shell idioms, and should work in both `zsh` and `bash`. The operations can be combined into a function:

```bash
phpPost() {
    php ${1:?script required} > ${2:?csv required} 2> ${3:?err required}
    [[ ! -s $2 ]] && rm $2
    [[ ! -s $3 ]] && rm $3
}
phpPost file.php data.csv error.txt
```

---

Option 2 - save `stdout` and `stderr` in shell variables, and only create the files if there is output:

```bash
php file.php \
    >  >(d=$(<&0) && [[ -n $d ]] && <<<$d >data.csv) \
    2> >(e=$(<&0) && [[ -n $e ]] && <<<$e >error.txt)
```

Some of the pieces:

- `>`, `2>` - redirect `stdout` and `stderr`.
- `>(...)` - process substitution. The shell creates a subprocess (sort of - see below) and sends the output that we've redirected to that process.
- `t=$(<&0)` - store the `stdin` of the subprocess in the variable `t`.
- `[[ -n ... ]]` - test if the string is non-empty.
- `<<<... > ...` - use a here-string to write the variable contents to a file.

This version comes with some caveats:

- It is specific to `zsh` (or more accurately, it did not work in my very brief tests with `bash`).
- This is not a common shell idiom.
- The files are not overwritten each time.
- Process substitutions can be run asynchronously by the shell, which means in some cases the initial command might finish before the output files are completely written. In this instance, the commands within the process substitution are all `zsh` built-ins, so the shell runs them synchronously within a single process. Other variations of this pattern might behave differently - the [zsh documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Process-Substitution) describes a workaround if that is an issue.

This can also be written as a function:

```bash
phpVars() {
    rm ${2:?} ${3:?} 2>/dev/null
    php ${1:?} \
        >  >(d=$(<&0) && [[ -n $d ]] && <<<$d >${2}) \
        2> >(e=$(<&0) && [[ -n $e ]] && <<<$e >${3})
}
phpVars file.php data.csv error.txt
```

---

Alternative solutions:

- It may be easier to detect whether the `php` command succeeded by testing the [shell return code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2180328) instead of looking at the output files.
- If updating the `php` code is a possibility, that script could write directly to the data and error files instead of passing the information through the shell.

Comment: Option 1 worked for my needs, though credit to DaveyBoy's first replace for the starting point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You redirect each stream to separate locations.

`php file.php > outfile.csv 2> errorlog.txt`

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file for more details

Comment: An empty file would be created based on if the output is to STDERR or STDOUT (at least in zsh). See Gairfowl's reply to my OP. What's the best way to remove that empty file?

Comment: You could test which file is empty and remove this one. Are you having a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? Looks like you're trying something complicated.